# Text 2 Speech. Появилась потребность использовать какой-нибудь синтезатор на русском. Есть варианты?

Tags: python, python-3.x, искусственный-интеллект, text-to-speech

Появилась потребность использовать какой-нибудь синтезатор. Что-то наподобие yandex speechkit только бесплатный и для коммерческих целей. Есть идеи? Должно быть на русском. Может быть можем тренить модельку сами. Желательно питон

Comment: Есть rtx 3090 + 32 gb ram + 500 gb ssd m2

Answer (score 1):

Можно и самому модель сделать, но готовые варианты всегда быстрее и проще использовать: https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/text-to-speech/
В этой статье можете найти основную полезную инфу по библиотеке Pyttsx, она должна подойти для описанных вами задач

PS.Tacotron 2 ,Mozilla TTS, ESPnet, DeepSpeech, WaveNet тоже должны подойти

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'engine'

Comment: Очень плохо распознает даже слово привет((

Comment: @DanielAzamat есть еще: Tacotron 2 ,Mozilla TTS, ESPnet, DeepSpeech, WaveNet
Они все имеют свои особенности, так что вам надо будет выбрать наиболее подходящую

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй TTS Vosk. Он современный, быстрый и легкий.
Документация - https://alphacephei.com/vosk/
GitHub репозиторий - https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api